# Show that a functional is continuous and differentiable

Tags: analysis, optimization

Let $v \in \mathcal{D'([0,1])}$ be a solution of the following Euler-Lagrange equation: 
$ -  ((v_x)^3)_x - \frac{5^3}{4^4}  v^\frac{-9}{5} = 0 $.
We now consider the functional F defined by: $F(x)= ( v(0)-(3/4) )^{2}$ where $x \in [0,1]$ . 
How can i show that F is continuous differentiable ?
Thank you for your help;

Comment: where is $x$ in the definition of $F$?

Comment: there's no $x$ in the definition of F. What i want to do is optimize this function numerically by giving different values of x at each iteration, and find the value of x for which v(0)=3/4, that's why the function is defined this way.

Comment: "find the value of x for which v(0)=3/4" I really am not sure what this means. If v were a function which had x as a parameter, rather than an input variable, then this makes sense, and of course, we might expect that there is a family of solutions to this equation. So it seems like you're asking to pick a particular v by its initial condition... but what you want to do with it is unclear.

Comment: Okay let me clear this a little bit since i tried to simplify the expressions which made them unclear. The functional F has an input $ Ki $ which is a distance, and the goal is to find the critical distance $Ki*$ for which the deviation v takes the value (3/4) in 0 i.e v(0)=3/4. so F is going to take different values of $Ki$ numerically till i reach that condition on v. Hope things are clearer now.

Comment: well F(Ki*)=0, when Ki had reached its critical value, the conditions on v is verified

Comment: I think that the input to $F$ is supposed to be $v$, rather than $x$; this seems to make everything much clearer. It seems like you have some method to bypass putting "all of $v$" into $F$ by only giving the functional some parameter $Ki$; I'm not entirely sure what this is but you've mentioned "deviation" and at this point I'm willing to believe that my confusion is just my inexperience with optimization problems

Comment: i understand, i'm just confused now on the continuity and differentiability of F since i need to calculate its derivative. Anyways,Thanks so much for your time.